# DevExpress Set XtraTab Selected Page

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I was trying to set the XtraTab Selected page in the constructor it self as follows,

```
 public frmInquiryManagement()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tabInquiryManagement.SelectedTabPage = xtraTabPage3;

        }
```

But it doesn't work that way. Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

XtraTabControl does not provide this method to directly set a selected page. What i see is, to implement this method, we need to implement a loop internally.

```
for(int i = 0; i < xtraTabControl1.TabPages.Count; i ++)
                if(xtraTabControl1.TabPages[i].Name == "someName"){
                    xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage = xtraTabControl1.TabPages[i];
                    break;
                }
```

Else this is one of the clear solutions :

```
tabpage1.Show();
tabpage1.pageVisible=true;
xtraTabControl1.tabPages[0].selected=true;
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers.

Comment: Still it displays the first tab page

Comment: Which way did you use?

Comment: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraTabXtraTabControl_SelectedTabPagetopic
Do have a look at this once. Check if the page that you are trying to set is not disabled for some reason.

Comment: Try setting the Page using the XtraTabControl.SelectedTabPageIndex Property.
Do vote up or accept if it helps.
thanks and cheers.

Comment: No its not disabled, I did set the page easily by a button click event with the same code, but I cannot do it by the constructor, That's the problem

Comment: Add a break point to the XtraTabControl.SelectedPageChanged Event and see what happens when you make this selection change from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve that you must use PageEnabled property from XtraTabPage component.

```
xtraTabPage3.PageEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectTabByTitle("xtraTabPage3",xtraTabControl1);
    }

    private void SelectTabByTitle(String tabTitle, XtraTabControl tabControl)
    {
        if (tabControl != null)
        {
            XtraTabPage pageToSelect = (from curPage in tabControl.TabPages
                                        where curPage.Text == tabTitle
                                        select curPage).FirstOrDefault();
            if (pageToSelect != null)
            {
                tabControl.SelectedTabPage = pageToSelect;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get an error in "from curPage in tabControl.TabPages" part saying "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type...."

Comment: Did you pass through the correct xtraTabControl? Also, this works by selecting the Tab that has 'xtraTabPage3' as a title.

Answer (score 0):

`xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPageIndex = 0;`, where 0 is the index of the page you wish to display.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should normally work, but it seems that the problem is that the Form has not loaded yet and the Tabs are not visible yet.  Try setting the `SelectedTabPage` on the `Load` event, or the `Shown` event

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in the Form's `Load` event handler:

```
        tabInquiryManagement.SelectedTabPage = xtraTabPage3;
        tabInquiryManagement.MakePageVisible(xtraTabPage3);
```